# CSS Transform Rotate letter alignment

Tags: html, css, transform

Im using CSS Transforms to rotate an h2 5deg.

For some reason the letters are out of alignment.

Take a look at an example here

http://dev.bestprintideas.com/bpi/image.png

Heres the CSS

```
.note-offer h2 { 
    color: #626262;
    text-shadow: none;
    text-transform: none;
    margin: 15px 0 10px 25px;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
}
```

HTML

```
  <div class="note-offer">
    <div class="clip"></div>
      <h2>
         <span class="orange">The&nbsp;Essentials</span> <div>Package</div>
      </h2>
      <img src="http://mydomain.com/123/200-tag.png">
      <p>Duis lobortis ligula vitae mauris lobortis congue. Morbi cursus  porttitor feugiat. Aliquam tempus, nunc sed tempor volutpat, dolor lorem  mollis quam, a elementum sapien purus ac&nbsp;
          <a class="read-more" href="http://dev.bestprintideas.com/bpi/offers/the-essentials-package/">Learn more…</a>
      </p>
 </div>
```

Why is this happening? Does anyone know how to fix it. Its happening in both FF 3.6 and Chrome 5

EDIT: It seems to work correctly in Chrome 5 for Win and mac but not linux. Its having issues in FF 3.6 for Win, Mac, linux and its working perfectly in Safari 5 on Mac

Comment: Could be a problem in the rendering engine of the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an [issue with this in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=518172) which has been fixed, broken and fixed again.  It may be possible to work around by using a different font (because different font types use a different rendering path), or you could live with it until the browsers get it sorted out.

Comment: It seems to happen with all fonts...

I guess I'll live with it and hope it gets fixed by the time FF 4 and Chrome 6 is out.

Comment: Would you happen to know if this is documented anywere? Im unable to find it.

Comment: @jef2904 You mean apart from in the defect I linked to in my answer?  What sort of documentation are you looking for?

Comment: may be a bugzilla link to the bug?

Comment: @jef2904 What I linked to in my answer is a bug in bugzilla.